# Django relationship mappings to GroupSettings

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to map my custom model for external tools to a group in a way that I can select which group has the access to a specific tool. I am bad with these relationship mappings. How do I do this?

```
class ExternalTool(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    allowed_for_groups = ????

class Group(models.Model):
... (django model)
```

I guess it has something to do with foreignkey, or onetomany, manytoone relations. So a group can access one or many external tools.

Comment: "group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Can an external tool be allowed for multiple groups? Can a group have access to multiple external tools? If so, then there is a many to many relationship between `ExternalTool` and `Group`.

In a database, the way you'd resolve this is by using a bridge table.

```
[ ExternalTOol ] ---< [Bridge ] >--- [ Group ]
```

This means, you create a bridge table that has a foreign key to both `ExternalTool` and `Group`. In Django, this translates to the following models

```
class ExternalTool(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    externaltools  = models.ManyToManyField(ExternalTool,
                          through="ExternalToolGroupMapping",
                          verbose_name="list of external tools",
                          related_name="groups")
    ...


class ExternalToolGroupMapping(models.Model):
    """ An intersection table between ExternalTool and Group """
    externaltool = models.ForeignKey(ExternalTool)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    ...
```

Now you can get a **list of groups of an external tool** using `et.groups` (where `et` is an instance of `ExternalTool`. And you can get a **list of external tools for a group** using `g.externaltools` (where `g` is an instance of `Group`)

Comment: Yes it's allowed for multiple groups. Isn't this against django? Can't I just use django-like features like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.

I was able to create a database table with "ManyToManyField(Group)" and migrating it with south. Now I have a DB table which contains id, external tool id and group id

Comment: No, it's not against Django. Infact, that's what the `through` attribute is for on the `ManyToManyField`.  The `through` attribute just lets you specify the model that you can actually access (in this case `ExternalToolGroupMapping`)